# How to fetch a BMP image in the bank and show it in the view, using Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a BMP image saved in the database, but this file is already in the database and was not included by the framework. I would just like to know how I can display this image in the view.

In Controller:

I got all the result of my query and I went to view:

```
$query = Query::all();
return view('way', ['query' => $query]);
```

In View:

```
<img src="{{asset('data:image/bmp;base64,'.base64_encode($query->result).'')}}">
```

I tried other shapes available on the internet and I did not succeed.

Comment: OK, it looks like you have all the code pieces in place. Have you debugged it? My first guess is that you need to Base64 **decode** it when fetching the image data.

Comment: In what way is the BMP stored in the database?

Comment: @halfer Apparently everything is all right, I do not know what could be wrong.

Comment: @DannyThunder Through a game, the character changes the emblem of the guild and automatically this image is saved in the registry of your guild in the database.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - `base64_encode` is correct. OK, next question - does your browser understand BMP images? It is not an internet standard, as far as I know - maybe only IE would load this? Have you tried PNG format instead?

Comment: @halfer I've never tried other formats, maybe you're right, do you have any idea how I convert the image format?

Comment: Sure, just install ImageMagick on your local machine, and do `convert image.bmp image.png` for every image you have. Try one first, of course, before converting many, to see if that's the problem.

Comment: If the image on the bench comes through a game the question is .... How to convert an image without having its file, this ImageMagick does it?

Comment: (Remember that, when you reply to people on Stack Overflow, you must use their handle, like `@halfer`, otherwise they are unlikely to see your message).

Comment: If images are generated dynamically by another program, then yes, you can still use ImageMagick. You can either do this when the image is stored to the database (best) or when you retrieve it (acceptable but not ideal). You will need ImageMagick installed on your server, [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

Comment: @halfer Okay, thanks, I'll try and return with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actualy don't use asset, just the inside code:

```
<img src="{{ 'data:image/bmp;base64,'.base64_encode($query->result) }}">
```

Base 64 extensions should exist as they are not part of Twig as I know.

Comment: Thanks for poiting out, but the semantics are the same right? If you take asset() call out should work, what did you think?

Comment: I did exactly as you said and should have solved, but it did not work, when I removed the asset from the tag, the error disappeared, the code does not generate more error, just the image does not appear, everything runs normal but nothing appears.

Comment: Thanks so much for help-me !